# Pass session attribute from jsp to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, session-variables, httpsession

I'm trying to pass a `HTTP Session` attribute from a JSP page to a JavaScript function written in external JS file. When I'm writing JS part in body section without writing specific function it works fine but when I declare a function and try to pass session attribute as a parameter it gives following error.

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
```

I have tried following methods to pass session attribute to JS function:

```
<body onload="popListbox(<%=session.getAttribute("objNames")%>)">

<body onload="popListbox(${objNames})">
```

after execution body tag looks like this:

```
<body national_id","birth_certificate"])"="" onload="popListbox(["></body>
```

Can someone tell me why body tag looks like above and how should I pass the parameter to JS function.

Comment: there should be another quote at the start of national_id and also a box bracket is missing..

Comment: Try setting the `onload` value with single quotes, not double quotes. The result of `session.getAttribute()` is using double quotes, so the nested quoting is messed up

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone actually whole `national_id","birth_certificate"])"=""` part should be in popuListbox fuction call as a parameter but its get misplaced after execution. thats the problem i face

Comment: @Sajirupee try this `<body onload="popListbox(<%=session.getAttribute('objNames')%>)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use single quotes for the attribute, i.e. `onload='...'` - right now your data string contains double quotes which break everything as they terminate the attribute.

However, it would be much better to keep using double quotes and HTML-escape any special characters (`"`, `&`, `<` and `>`) in `objNames`! That way you don't get any problems if the data contains single quotes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your quotes are creating a problem.i.e they are conflicting..Try using single quotes...

```
<body onload='popListbox(<%=session.getAttribute("objNames")%>)'>
```

Comment: Those quotes are fine as they are part of server-side code. The actual problem lies in the fact that his function returns JSON which uses double quotes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster v meet again(if u remember that is)...even i had a similar problem before but i solved with single quote as  in my answer

Comment: Using single quotes for attribute names gives an error. but replacing double quotes in `onLoad` event resolved my issue. thank you for your help.